# web.config transform for environments without build configurations

Tags: octopus-deploy, web.config-transform

I really like the ability of visual studio 2012 to be able to preview a transform along with a comparison with the original web.config. But in order for this to work, the transforms must be created based on build configurations.

is there a way to be able to preview transforms in the same way, without having to create build configurations for each environment?

(for deployment i use octopus deploy so there is no need for these transforms to work with publish functionality provided by vs)

Comment: Could you use a tool like [this](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/) instead?

Comment: this tool is lacking the comparison with the original base config. visual studio ui for this is way better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! You can create a publish profile with the same name as the transformation config name, and the preview transform will work, without having a build configuration for it.
The cool thing is that you don't have to actually use the publish profile (publish the application)... just save the pubxml andd voila right click on transform -> preview transform!

Read More: http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,fdcc88bf-95ac-4945-a49b-96d9d1ac35a5.aspx